# Autopopulate cells with value from In-cell dropdown list - VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, drop-down-menu

**Goal**

I would like to loop through three sheets (I'm starting with one), look for a certain Type in column C and automatically populate/autopopulate a In-cell dropdown (similar to the one found in the Data Validation settings) in column D. The In-cell dropdown should list values for all Types but should autopopulate with the value belong to the Type.

**Problem**

The code below populates every In-cell dropdown list with the same value, namely Type1's Item1--Item2--Item3--Item4.

I don't know how to list all values and at the same time autopopulate the cell.

**Desired output**

[image]

**Code**

For the sake of simplicity, I have only added the two first types in the code below.

```
Sub AutoDropdown()

Dim PersonSource As Range
Dim PersonSourceTotal As Range
Dim PersonCell As Range
'Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer

Set PersonSourceTotal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D200")

With PersonSourceTotal.Offset(0, -2)
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, PersonSourceTotal.Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set PersonSource = Sheets("sheet1").Range("D2:D" & lastRow)

On Error Resume Next

For Each PersonCell In PersonSource
    Name = PersonCell.Offset(0, -3)
    ID = PersonCell.Offset(0, -2)
        If Name <> "" And ID <> "" Then
            For i = 0 To lastRow
                If PersonCell.Offset(i, -1) = "Type1" Then
                    arr1 = Array("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4")
                    arr1Merged = Join(arr1, "--")
                    With PersonCell.Validation
                                                .Delete
                                                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                                                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=arr1Merged
                                                .IgnoreBlank = True
                                                .InCellDropdown = True
                                                .InputTitle = ""
                                                .ErrorTitle = ""
                                                .InputMessage = ""
                                                .ErrorMessage = ""
                                                .ShowInput = True
                                                .ShowError = True
                    End With
                ElseIf PersonCell.Offset(i, -1) = "Type2" Then
                    arr2 = Array("Item5", "Item6", "Item7", "Item8", "Item9")
                    arr2Merged = Join(arr2, "--")
                    Debug.Print (arr2Merged)
                    With PersonCell.Validation
                                                .Delete
                                                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                                                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=arr2Merged
                                                .IgnoreBlank = True
                                                .InCellDropdown = True
                                                .InputTitle = ""
                                                .ErrorTitle = ""
                                                .InputMessage = ""
                                                .ErrorMessage = ""
                                                .ShowInput = True
                                                .ShowError = True
                    End With
                End If
            Next i
        Else
            MsgBox "Remember to add Name and ID"
        End If
Next PersonCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

After your comments I've updated the code to try to better reflect your requirements:

```
Sub AutoDropdown()
Dim PersonSource As Range
Dim PersonSourceTotal As Range
Dim PersonCell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim SelectionArray(1 To 4) As String

Set PersonSourceTotal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D200")

With PersonSourceTotal.Offset(0, -2)
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, PersonSourceTotal.Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set PersonSource = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D" & lastRow)

arr1 = Array("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4") 'Define your selections items
arr2 = Array("Item5", "Item6", "Item7", "Item8", "Item9")
arr3 = Array("ItemE", "ItemF", "ItemG", "ItemH")
arr4 = Array("ItemA", "ItemB", "ItemC", "ItemD")

SelectionArray(1) = Join(arr1, "--") 'join the selections into another array
SelectionArray(2) = Join(arr2, "--")
SelectionArray(3) = Join(arr3, "--")
SelectionArray(4) = Join(arr4, "--")
AllSelections = Join(SelectionArray, ",") 'group all selections for data validation
On Error Resume Next

For Each PersonCell In PersonSource
    VarName = PersonCell.Offset(0, -3)
    ID = PersonCell.Offset(0, -2)
        If VarName <> "" And ID <> "" Then
            Select Case PersonCell.Offset(i, -1).Value
                Case "Type1"
                    With PersonCell.Validation
                        .Delete
                        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=AllSelections
                    End With
                    PersonCell.Value = SelectionArray(1)
                Case "Type2"
                    With PersonCell.Validation
                        .Delete
                        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=AllSelections
                    End With
                    PersonCell.Value = SelectionArray(2)
                Case "Type3"
                    With PersonCell.Validation
                        .Delete
                        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=AllSelections
                    End With
                    PersonCell.Value = SelectionArray(3)
                Case "Type4"
                With PersonCell.Validation
                        .Delete
                        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=AllSelections
                    End With
                    PersonCell.Value = SelectionArray(4)
                Case Else
                    MsgBox "No Type was entered on Column C"
            End Select
        Else
            MsgBox "Remember to add VarName and ID"
        End If
Next PersonCell
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

To get the above code to run automatically when a the value of Column C (ie. Type Number) is changed then you should add the following code under Sheet1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 3 Then AutoDropdown 'if a value is changed on Column 3/ Column C then call the name of the above subroutine, in this case it is called AutoDropdown
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Xabier. I diasgree :) I have tested again just to make sure. The cells are not autopopulated, and only the value for Type1 (Item1--Item2--Item3--Item4) appears.

Comment: You can do this with formulas in the data validation. see the link
http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html If you what to try that method I can provide the formulas.

Comment: @Xabier, your code autopopulates correctly! :) I have changed this part of your code to also display the values in the list correctly: `Formula1:=arr1Merged` and `Formula1:=arr2Merged`. Only thing missing is to display both `arr1Merged` and `arr2Merged` in the dropdown list. I think I can use `Split(arr1Merged & "," & arr2Merged, ",") `, but this is just for two. There will be four in total. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Another possibility would be to define something like: `tot = Array("Item1--Item2--Item3--Item4", "Item5--Item6--Item7--Item8--Item9")`and `Total = Join(tot, ",")` and then apply it to `Formula1`. But I would like to reuse `arr1Merged` and `arr2Merged`.

Comment: @Saud I've updated my answer, please have a try and let me know if it works for you, or if it doesn't what is the issue might be, as I've tried it and I believe it does what you wanted, I would probably re-design the code to make it easier to add new Items, but for the task at hand it will do what you expect...

Comment: @Xabier, it does the trick. How would you go about automatically updating the cell value in column D if the Type is changed in column C?

Comment: Updated my answer to call the subroutine any time the value in column C is changed. Please could you accept my response as an answer as it does what you wanted it to...? Thank you.